# Migrate site to an android Application using Webview

Tags: android, webview, android-camera

I successfully migrated my site to an android application using webview. My site requires that you upload a photo, but am not able to access local files or Android camera from my app. How do I make it work?

Here is my MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.oscar.lostnfound;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.ConsoleMessage;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private WebView webView;
private ProgressBar progress;
Button button;
final Activity activity = this;
public Uri imageUri;

public static final int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE  = 2888;
public ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
public Uri mCapturedImageURI = null;
// @Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    //webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    //other webview settings
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);


    String url = "http://codeupset.com/academy-form";
    webView.loadUrl(url);
    progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);

    startWebView();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
  @JavascriptInterface
   public void startWebView(){

  webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                               //@Override
                               public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                                   view.loadUrl(url);
                                   return true;

                               }

                               boolean bReceivedError = false;

       //@Override
       public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                                   String description, String failingUrl) {
           bReceivedError = true;
           setContentView(R.layout.error);
           button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Check Internet connection",
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           //On click listener
           View.OnClickListener retry = new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {

                   webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
                   setContentView(R.layout.webview);
                   String url = "http://codeupset.com";
                   webView.loadUrl(url);
               }
           };
           // set OnClickListner for the button
           button.setOnClickListener(retry);
       }

       //@Override
       public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
           progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           MainActivity.this.progress.setProgress(100);
           super.onPageFinished(view, url);
       }

      // @Override
       public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
           progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           MainActivity.this.progress.setProgress(0);
           super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                               }

 });


          webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

              // openFileChooser for Android 3.0+
              @JavascriptInterface
              public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) {

                  // Update message
                  mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;

                  try {

                      // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard

                      File imageStorageDir = new File(
                              Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                                      Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                              , "AndroidExampleFolder");

                      if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
                          // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
                          imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
                      }

                      // Create camera captured image file path and name
                      File file = new File(
                              imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_"
                                      + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())
                                    + ".jpg");

                      mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(file);

                     // Camera capture image intent
                      final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(
                              android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                      captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);

                      Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                      i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                      i.setType("image/*");

                      // Create file chooser intent
                      Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, "Image Chooser");

                      // Set camera intent to file chooser
                      chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS
                              , new Parcelable[]{captureIntent});

                      // On select image call onActivityResult method of activity
                      startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);

                  } catch (Exception e) {
                      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Exception:" + e,
                              Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  }

              }

              // openFileChooser for Android < 3.0
             @JavascriptInterface
              public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
                  openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
              }

              //openFileChooser for other Android versions
              @JavascriptInterface
              public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg,
                                          String acceptType,
                                          String capture) {

                  openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType);
              }


              // The webPage has 2 filechoosers and will send a
              // console message informing what action to perform,
              // taking a photo or updating the file

              public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cm) {

                  onConsoleMessage(cm.message(), cm.lineNumber(), cm.sourceId());
                  return true;
              }

          });   // End setWebChromeClient

    }



// Return here when file selected from camera or from SDcard

 @Override
 @JavascriptInterface
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
    Intent intent) {

    if(requestCode==FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)
    {

    if (null == this.mUploadMessage) {
    return;

    }

    Uri result=null;

    try{
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {

    result = null;

    } else {

    // retrieve from the private variable if the intent is null
    result = intent == null ? mCapturedImageURI : intent.getData();
    }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "activity :"+e,
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
    mUploadMessage = null;

    }

    }




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
public void setValue(int progress) {
    this.progress.setProgress(progress);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
}
```

Here is My Xml(webview.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<WebView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:indeterminate="false" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Logcat

```html
04-16 09:30:56.116  28887-28887/com.example.oscar.lostnfound I/SnapScrollController﹕ setSnapScrollingMode case-default no-op
04-16 09:30:56.251  28887-28887/com.example.oscar.lostnfound I/SnapScrollController﹕ setSnapScrollingMode case-default no-op
04-16 09:30:56.266  28887-28887/com.example.oscar.lostnfound I/ScaleGestureDetector﹕ TwScaleGestureDetector
04-16 09:31:58.906  28887-28887/com.example.oscar.lostnfound W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
04-16 09:32:42.196  30041-30041/com.example.oscar.lostnfound W/ApplicationPackageManager﹕ getCSCPackageItemText()
04-16 09:32:42.201  30041-30041/com.example.oscar.lostnfound I/PersonaManager﹕ getPersonaService() name persona_policy
04-16 09:32:42.281  30041-30041/com.example.oscar.lostnfound V/WebViewChromium﹕ Binding Chromium to the background looper Looper (main, tid 1) {431a6968}
04-16 09:32:42.286  30041-30041/com.example.oscar.lostnfound I/chromium﹕ [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(112)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
04-16 09:32:42.286  30041-30041/com.example.oscar.lostnfound I/BrowserProcessMain﹕ Initializing chromium process, renderers=0
04-16 09:32:42.301  30041-30072/com.example.oscar.lostnfound W/chromium﹕ [WARNING:proxy_service.cc(888)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
04-16 09:32:42.301  30041-30041/com.example.oscar.lostnfound W/ApplicationPackageManager﹕ getCSCPackageItemText()
04-16 09:32:42.656  30041-30041/com.example.oscar.lostnfound D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
04-16 09:32:42.671  30041-30041/com.example.oscar.lostnfound D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: left = 468
04-16 09:32:42.671  30041-30041/com.example.oscar.lostnfound D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
04-16 09:32:42.671  30041-30041/com.example.oscar.lostnfound D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: right = 612
04-16 09:32:42.671  30041-30041/com.example.oscar.lostnfound D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 144
04-16 09:32:42.681  30041-30041/com.example.oscar.lostnfound W/AwContents﹕ nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
04-16 09:32:42.941  30041-30041/com.example.oscar.lostnfound I/chromium﹕ [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async pixel transfers not supported
04-16 09:32:43.016  30041-30041/com.example.oscar.lostnfound I/chromium﹕ [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async pixel transfers not supported
```

Answer (score 0):

> try this,

**activity_main.xml :-**

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:padding="10dp" >

  <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:padding="5dp" >

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSelectPhoto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Select Photo" />

  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:padding="10dp" >

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/viewImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

  </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

> Now create your main activity like this:-

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView viewImage;
    Button b;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSelectPhoto);
        viewImage=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.viewImage);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selectImage();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds options to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

      private void selectImage() {

        final CharSequence[] options = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery","Cancel" };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
        builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (options[item].equals("Take Photo"))
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                }
                else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery"))
                {
                    Intent intent = new   Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 2);

                }
                else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == 1) {
                File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
                for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
                    if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {
                        f = temp;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap;
                    BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),
                            bitmapOptions); 

                    viewImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                    String path = android.os.Environment
                            .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + File.separator
                            + "Phoenix" + File.separator + "default";
                    f.delete();
                    OutputStream outFile = null;
                    File file = new File(path, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
                    try {
                        outFile = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, outFile);
                        outFile.flush();
                        outFile.close();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else if (requestCode == 2) {

                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePath, null, null, null);
                c.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
                String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
                c.close();
                Bitmap thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
                Log.w("path of image from gallery......******************.........", picturePath+"");
                viewImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Actually I placed my web app inside a web view in Android. In my web app I have a JS Library which allows me to pick files form different sources including local files. The issue is when inside my view I try to access the camera or local files the web view doesn't allow me to do that.

Comment: If you've set your targetSdkVersion to 17 or higher, you must add the @JavascriptInterface annotation to any method that you want available to your JavaScript (the method must also be public). If you do not provide the annotation, the method is not accessible by your web page when running on Android 4.2 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

> I got you point...try this,

```
public class ShowWebView extends Activity {

    //private Button button;
    private WebView webView;
    final Activity activity = this;
    public Uri imageUri;

    private static final int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE   = 2888;
    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
    private Uri mCapturedImageURI = null;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.show_web_view);

        //Get webview 
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        // Define url that will open in webview 
        String webViewUrl = "http://www.yourWebsite.com";



        // Javascript inabled on webview  
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        // Other webview options
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

        //webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

        //Other webview settings
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true); 

        //Load url in webview
        webView.loadUrl(webViewUrl);

        // Define Webview manage classes
        startWebView(); 

    } 

    private void startWebView() {



        // Create new webview Client to show progress dialog
        // Called When opening a url or click on link
        // You can create external class extends with WebViewClient 
        // Taking WebViewClient as inner class

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {      
            ProgressDialog progressDialog;

            //If you will not use this method url links are open in new brower not in webview
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {              

                // Check if Url contains ExternalLinks string in url 
                // then open url in new browser
                // else all webview links will open in webview browser
                if(url.contains("google")){ 

                    // Could be cleverer and use a regex
                    //Open links in new browser
                    view.getContext().startActivity(
                            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));

                    // Here we can open new activity

                    return true;

                } else {

                    // Stay within this webview and load url
                    view.loadUrl(url); 
                    return true;
                }

            }



            //Show loader on url load
            public void onLoadResource (WebView view, String url) {

                // if url contains string androidexample
                // Then show progress  Dialog
                if (progressDialog == null && url.contains("androidexample") 
                        ) {

                    // in standard case YourActivity.this
                    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ShowWebView.this);
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                    progressDialog.show();
                }
            }

            // Called when all page resources loaded
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                try{
                    // Close progressDialog
                    if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        progressDialog = null;
                    }
                }catch(Exception exception){
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }); 


        // You can create external class extends with WebChromeClient 
        // Taking WebViewClient as inner class
        // we will define openFileChooser for select file from camera or sdcard

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

            // openFileChooser for Android 3.0+
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType){  

                // Update message
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;

                try{    

                    // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard

                    File imageStorageDir = new File(
                                           Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                                           Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                                           , "AndroidExampleFolder");

                    if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
                        // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
                        imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
                    }

                    // Create camera captured image file path and name 
                    File file = new File(
                                    imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_" 
                                    + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) 
                                    + ".jpg");

                    mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(file); 

                    // Camera capture image intent
                    final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(
                                                  android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                    captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);

                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); 
                    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                    i.setType("image/*");

                    // Create file chooser intent
                    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, "Image Chooser");

                    // Set camera intent to file chooser 
                    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS
                                           , new Parcelable[] { captureIntent });

                    // On select image call onActivityResult method of activity
                    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);

                  }
                 catch(Exception e){
                     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Exception:"+e, 
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 }

            }

            // openFileChooser for Android < 3.0
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg){
                openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
            }

            //openFileChooser for other Android versions
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, 
                                       String acceptType, 
                                       String capture) {

                openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType);
            }



            // The webPage has 2 filechoosers and will send a 
            // console message informing what action to perform, 
            // taking a photo or updating the file

            public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cm) {  

                onConsoleMessage(cm.message(), cm.lineNumber(), cm.sourceId());
                return true;
            }

            public void onConsoleMessage(String message, int lineNumber, String sourceID) {
                //Log.d("androidruntime", "Show console messages, Used for debugging: " + message);

            }
        });   // End setWebChromeClient

    }



    // Return here when file selected from camera or from SDcard

    @Override  
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,  
                                       Intent intent) { 

     if(requestCode==FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)  
     {  

            if (null == this.mUploadMessage) {
                return;

            }

           Uri result=null;

           try{
                if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {

                    result = null;

                } else {

                    // retrieve from the private variable if the intent is null
                    result = intent == null ? mCapturedImageURI : intent.getData(); 
                } 
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "activity :"+e,
                 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUploadMessage = null;

     }

    }

    // Open previous opened link from history on webview when back button pressed

    @Override
    // Detect when the back button is pressed
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if(webView.canGoBack()) {

            webView.goBack();

        } else {
            // Let the system handle the back button
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

}
```

> hopefully your xml file is like this,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <WebView  
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>       
</LinearLayout>
```

> also add these permissions in your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Didn't still work for me.. can we connect on TeamViewer so you can see my code?

Comment: sorry buddy, not possible for me to be on teamViewer, Please post your code here with your logcat .